# cross compiling a kernel with backports

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, cross-compilation

I have a "backport" which consists of a makefile that produces some ko files for device driver support. It also comes with some binaries that are dropped on to the host machine in addition to these ko files. I want to see if my understanding of the kernel compilation process is correct:

I assume what I should do is configure any of the backported functionality to be "M"/module and compile the kernel. The kernel will then produce ko files as appropriate for the configured functionality. I will then run the backport makefile, which will overwrite those ko files with my "backported" functionality. Now, at this point can I issue a command to generate an image from the kernel compilation?

I think some of my uncertainty spawns from the following:

1. Does changing the menuconfig not take effect until a recompile?
2. Does dropping in a ko file cause the kernel to compile differently, assuming the ko file changed.

Comment: Does the Linux kernel already provide drivers for these devices ? Do you get the source code for the drivers you want ? What do you mean with "backport" ?

Comment: @MC68020 I assume the kernel can offer support for these devices, because there are menuconfig entries for them. By backport I mean it is source code and a makefile that produce kernel module ko files.

Comment: So you mean the kernel gets some support for these devices which, for whatever reason, you are not pleased with. You also mean you get the sources for other drivers for the same devices. Then, my stupid question : why don't you just patch the kernel drivers and then just simply leave kernel's make deal with everything ?

Comment: thats right, the idea is that im overwriting the kernel modules with different ones.
When ou say patch the kernel drivers do you mean overwrite their source code with mine or do you mean overwrite the ko files. As you will see from my question, im not really clear on how the kernel compiles the ko files and links them.

Comment: Overwrite kernel source code ! Yes indeed. Make a patch from the diff between you kernel source distribution and your source then apply the patch then make & make-modules… Of course you should first backup your kernel source distribution and of course first be dead sure that your own sources are compatible with the kernel version you will be patching.